# Missing Error For - PayPal Adaptive Payments API Error

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to create a program that will pay users using the PayPal Adaptive Payments API. I'm trying to implement the implicit payments method of paying users (so I don't have to approve every one). I'm currently dynamically passing the PayPal credentials in using a Dictionary for the configuration, like so:

```
accountConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
accountConfig.Add("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", "I HAVE PUT MY USERID HERE");
accountConfig.Add("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE", "MY SIGNATURE HERE"
accountConfig.Add("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD", "MY PASSWORD HERE");
accountConfig.Add("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATIONID", "APP-80W284485P519543T");
accountConfig.Add("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");
accountConfig.Add("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");
```

Then, I'm configuring the payment as follows:

```
AdaptivePaymentsService aps = new AdaptivePaymentsService(accountConfig);
Receiver receiver = new Receiver { email = "RECEIVER EMAIL", amount = payment.CommissionAmount };
List<Receiver> l = new List<Receiver> { receiver };
RequestEnvelope re = new RequestEnvelope { errorLanguage = "en_US" };
PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest(
    re,
    "SERVICE",
    "http://cancelUrl",
    "USD",
    new ReceiverList(l),
    "http://returnUrl");
payRequest.senderEmail = "I HAVE PUT MY USERID HERE";
aps.Pay(payRequest);
```

According to the documentation, under the implicit payments section, you should be able to use the API caller's account email as the sender email and this is considered implicit payment. However, where should I be doing this? If I do it like above, adding it to the `payRequest`, I get a `MissingCredentialException` with the following error message:

```
Missing credentials for
```

There's no other information. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here are the exception details:

```
PayPal.Exception.MissingCredentialException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Missing credentials for 
  Source=PayPalCoreSDK
  StackTrace:
       at PayPal.NVP.PlatformAPICallPreHandler..ctor(Dictionary`2 config, String rawPayload, String serviceName, String method, String apiUserName, String accessToken, String accesstokenSecret)
       at PayPal.AdaptivePayments.AdaptivePaymentsService.Pay(PayRequest payRequest, String apiUserName)
       at PayPal.AdaptivePayments.AdaptivePaymentsService.Pay(PayRequest payRequest)
       at MyApp.PayPalAdapter.PayPerson(Person person, Payment payment, String returnUrl, String cancelUrl) in c:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\PayPalAdapter.cs:line 50
       at MyApp.Scripts.ManagePersonPaymentsJob.PayPerson(Person person, Payment payment) in c:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.Scripts\ManagePersonPaymentsJob.cs:line 71
       at MyApp.Scripts.ManagePersonPaymentsJob.Run() in c:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.Scripts\ManagePersonPaymentsJob.cs:line 60
       at MyApp.Scripts.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.Scripts\Program.cs:line 47
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: have you look at and or read the entire documentation [Adaptive Payment Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Comment: Need to see the raw request and responses that you're getting, including headers.  I do this quite a bit and haven't had any issues with it, so you must be missing something somewhere.  I'll dig up a request so we can compare.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I've read quite a bit of it. If there's something I've clearly missed, could you point it out?

Comment: @AndrewAngell if you have any example code I could look at, that'd be helpful. I'm trying to get the request from mine, but I can't seem to capture it...

Comment: I work with PHP and XML so my samples probably won't do you much good.  If you can post a sample of your request, though, I can take a look and try to spot your issue.  It should be pretty easy to pull out your request.  At some point you must be passing it as a value into an HTTP request to PayPal.  Just save that to a log file or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was doing my credentials incorrectly, basically due to various different examples I found online.

In addition, I found [THIS](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox#credentialsModal) guide that ended up being the most helpful (and worked for me). I'm not sure why I didn't stumble upon this sooner. Hopefully it helps someone in the future.